# Switching Activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I've been researching a solution to my problem but not a single result fixes my problem.

I have five Java activities. Each activity has five buttons, four to the other activities and one to itself. It's basically just a bar of bottoms at the bottom of the page.

My issue is that let's say I'm in one activity, and then I click that button to the activity again, it opens and loads an entirely new activity. And then when I click back, it shows the previous activity open as I left it. But if I press it ten times, I need to click back ten times. Also, if I switch between each activity twice and I want to click back to main to exit, I need to click back ten times instead of five.

I want it to be such that when I click a button, it opens the activity. If I press the button again, it does nothing if I'm in that activity. And if I'm switching between activities and I repress an activity I already opened, I want that to be brought to the top of the stack from its lower location, not added. So at most, I only want five activities running. 
It's a very confusing problem as I see people suggesting to use intent flags, which I'm not sure if I place them in the manifest, which does nothing with I try. And I've seen people suggest using LaunchMode single instance, which also does nothing.

Comment: `... and one to itself` So what's the sense in having a Button which opens... the very same Activity you are already in?!

Comment: @Rotwang it's a constant ui. Think instagram. I could very easily just disable the button when it's on that page but it still doesn't fix the problem. If I open another page, and then open that page again, like say I just switch between pages by navigating the buttons, and I do this 100 times, then I'll need to click back 100 times. I want something where I only need to do it 5 at most at any given time.

Comment: @Rotwang and I still want to keep that button for future usage so I can repurpose it to refresh that activity when it's open.

Comment: So... what about **one Activity with 5 Fragments**? I don't use Instagram, so I don't know about its UI. And the Buttons *could* be Tabs, instead.

Comment: @Rotwang yes I keep seeing people recommend using fragments, and I might end up doing that, but I already have the entire project set up with all those activities. And one of those activities itself uses three fragments. So I'm not sure if I could use fragments within fragments. So even though I might end up using fragments in the future, it seems way too time consuming to go through and make all those changes right now and do so without screwing up the project and running into all sorts of errors

Comment: Design note: For me, it's easier to reason in terms of a fixed part (the container Activity) with the buttons (or TextViews or Tabs, or ImageViews... whatever is clickable and can contain graphics and/or text as well - so, an awful lot of widgets) and a "switchable" part (the current Fragment). This way, the desired Fragment would appear as soon as you touch the corresponding element.

Comment: May be [FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) will help you

Comment: @Vigen I looked into it but it wasn't helpful. I will investigate further though, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I really think fragments are the best method here. And yes, it's a little tricky but you can use fragments within fragments. For navigating without creating extra instances, I think you might be looking for something along the lines of this:

```
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if(id == R.id.nav_home){

        Fragment newFragment; 
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        // Look for fragment by tag
        Fragment foundFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(MAIN_FRAGMENT);

        if(foundFragment != null) { //if fragment's already in the backstack
            newFragment = foundFragment; //replace fragment with backstack fragment
        }else{
            newFragment = new MainFragment(); // use a new fragment instance
        }

        // Add new fragment instance to fragment manager
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment, MAIN_FRAGMENT)
                .addToBackStack(MAIN_FRAGMENT)
                .commit();

    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I'm really beginning to consider fragments then. Do you know how difficult it is to change from activities to fragments? Do I change all my code in the manifest? I'll do some digging but I think I'll probably have to start again from scratch if I'm using fragments. And how do they work? So would the content within the main activity also be a fragment? Or should I have nothing inside the main activity aside from the toolbar and bottom bar I made?

Comment: The manifest doesn't care about fragments so you can comment out the activity declarations in the manifest for the ones you want to change to fragments. The main activity would hold your navigation/menu and `FrameLayout`/fragment container. For changing your `Activities` to `Fragments`, there are a few differences in lifecycle methods but there's a lot of similarity for the most part so you can usually copy your code in and make some adjustments to use either `Fragment` versions of methods you had in your activity or `getActivity().`whateverYouWantToUse() to use the activity's version.